# Why might /dev/random not exist on a newly provided server?

Tags: debian

I've just started renting a new Debian Lenny server, but `/dev/random` is missing. However I can see `/dev/urandom`. Why might this be missing, and how can I create it?

Comment: Real physical server? OpenVZ container? Other virtualization?

Comment: @andol: Wondering the same, I have seen these devices not exist in openvz before.

Comment: Xen, apparently: http://xtrahost.co.uk/xenvps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get install udev`

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a Linux system without `/dev/random`. It should always be present (and in fact some servers rely on it). Just bug your provider about it, they need to fix it.

As to creating it yourself:

Normally it should be created by `udev` on bootup. If you don't use `udev`, you can create it yourself using `MAKEDEV`. But you should probably fix the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

This is a failure which sometimes happens with an update or a new installation. This should be fixed by your provider!! Tell him maybe he will do a new installation

Here is the right command to create the Random Device for yourself:

```
mknod /dev/random c 1 9
```

But you should tell it to your provider!

Here is another link that describes the problem: http://markus.revti.com/2007/12/creating-devrandom/